# How to use other html file if consumer is on mobile?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a problem idk how to let my consumer see my mobile html i used: 
But for some reason it doesnt want to work do you have nay suggestions?

````
    if (screen.width <= 500) {
    document.location = "webapp.html";
    } 
    </script> ```
````

Comment: You should just make your site responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `window.location.href = "webapp.html"` instead of what you are using?

Also you can try that thing before the page loads. If you are using PHP with CodeIgniter you could use the [User Agent class](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/user_agent.html) and detect what device is entering the page and after that redirect to the according page.

Answer (score 0):

Just make your site responsive using css3 flexbox or
css frameworks like bootstrap, etc.

Comment: -_- I just want a other application on mobile than on desktop

Comment: You can use the screen.width function of javascript to retrieve the width of the user's devices. Then depending on this width, you can redirect to the page in question using window.location.replace ('destination');